# Fazer logout quando browser fechar ou sessão finalizar

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que armazena no banco de dados quando usuário faz login e logout. Porém, a função de logout só é chamada quando o usuário clica em sair.

Queria saber se tem como chamar a função de logout quando o browser fechar ou a sessão finalizar.

Comment: Se a solução linkada acima ou resposta abaixo não resolver, queira [edit] a postagem detalhando melhor as peculiaridades e requisitos do seu caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia tentar utilizar a função 'onunload'

```
<body onunload="funcaoEventoSair()">

<script>
function funcaoEventoSair() {
    alert("SAIR"); // colocar sua lógica de log off aqui 
}
</script>
```

outra alternativa:

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        alert("SAIR"); // colocar sua lógica de log off aqui 
}
</script>
```